# angular and mic-recorder-to-mp3: Lame is not defined

Tags: angular, mp3, audio-recording

I wanted to add the mic-recorder-to-mp3 library to an angular app to record mp3 from the browser.

I added the library through:

npm install mic-recorder-to-mp3

Then I added the import at the top of the app.component.ts.

import * as Mic from 'mic-recorder-to-mp3';

When I start the app:
ng serve

I get the following error in the browser console:

```
index.js:15500 Uncaught ReferenceError: Lame is not defined
    at index.js:15500
    at index.js:2
    at Object../node_modules/mic-recorder-to-mp3/dist/index.js (index.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:351)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (environment.ts:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

I'm using: Angular CLI: 8.3.29, Node: 12.18.3, [package.json screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RudCz.png)

Could you help me how to add this do an angular project?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your polyfills.ts:

```
window.Lame = require("lamejs/src/js/Lame");
window.Presets = require("lamejs/src/js/Presets");
window.GainAnalysis = require("lamejs/src/js/GainAnalysis");
window.QuantizePVT = require("lamejs/src/js/QuantizePVT");
window.Quantize = require("lamejs/src/js/Quantize");
window.Reservoir = require("lamejs/src/js/Reservoir");
window.Takehiro = require("lamejs/src/js/Takehiro");
window.MPEGMode = require("lamejs/src/js/MPEGMode");
window.BitStream = require("lamejs/src/js/BitStream");
```